# Установка 1с битрикс управление сайтом

Tags: битрикс, error404

Пробую установить 1с битрикс управление сайтом. Зарегался на хостинге. Далее в папку закинул скрипт, перешёл на сайт установил путь /скрипт.php вышла установочная страница, начал установку и у меня перезагрузил ась страница с ошибкой. То есть дальше должна по идее вылезти установочная страница, но вышла ошибка (The requested URL /bitrix/urlrewrite.php was not found on this server. Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.), какие-то предустановки я должен делать? Может кто-то сталкивался

Comment: Скорее всего, проблема с .htaccess файлом в корневой директории. На локалке нормально сайт разворачивается?

Comment: да я просто на другом сервере развернулся

Comment: Проверьте версию PHP, скорее всего она ниже 7, поэтому выкидывает ошибку.